# Complex function plot issue

Tags: plotting, complex

I am plotting the real part of a simple complex function defined in two equivalent ways, and the plots do not agree.

```
r = 5; a = 1;
f1[z_] := -I ( 1/(r^2 - (a - I z)^2) )^(3/2)  ;
f2[z_] := ( -(1/(r^2 - (a - I z)^2)) )^(3/2)  ;
Plot[{Re[f1[z]], Re[f2[z]]}, {z, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Red, {Blue, Dashed}}]
```

Since

```
(-1)^(3/2) == -I
```

these definitions should agree.  However, the plots say otherwise.

[image: plots]

What's going on here?

Comment: You're assuming $(ab)^r=a^r b^r$ generally holds for complex $a$ and $b$. Have a look at this simple example: `{(-I)^(3/2), -I (I)^(3/2)} // N`.

Comment: I don't feel like this is the problem:

    (-1)^(3/2) / (-I) // N

returns 1.  Your given example also doesn't make sense, since isolating (-1)^(3/2) is I, not -I.  That accounts for your sign difference.

Comment: Yes, `(-1)^(3/2)` and `-I` are the same. You are then comparing `-I (w)^(3/2)` and `(-w)^(3/2)` (where `w == 1/(r^2 - (a - I z)^2)`). Do you now see the problem? And no, `(-1)^(3/2)` is not `I`. Did you try it out?

Comment: Are you familiar with the concepts of "principal value" and "branch cut"?

Comment: Yeah I got all twisted up there.  I needed to consider the angle in [0,2 pi) and not [-pi,pi).  Had just been working with an Arctan defined on the second interval.  Thanks for the boot to the head :)